What am I missing in my AdMob implementation?
I'm new to Android App Development, and I have read the documentation and watched a few videos about how to implement banner ads. However, I couldn't get it figured out. I'm not too sure where I'm messing up on the AdMob implementation code. I can see the "Ads By Google" banner ad in my activity_main.xml, but I cannot see any ad previews when launching the app.
build.gardle.kts (in dependencies):
implementation(libs.play.services.ads)

MainActivity.kt (in onCreate):
MobileAds.initialize(this@MainActivity) {}
 adView = findViewById<View>(R.id.adView) as AdView
 val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
 adView.loadAd(adRequest)

AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 ...
 <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
  android:value="(Insert App ID Here)"/>

activity_main.xml:
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="(Insert Unit Id Here)"/>


Are you using a test unit ID not your real one?

@Toru No, but even when I release it to my closed testing, I can't see the ads even after downloading the app.

First, you better use test unit ID(s) during the development. Then if your implementation works great with the test unit IDs, you do not need to worry about your implementation. Only you have to do is just to let your app use your real unit ID(s) in the release build. In case you don't see the AD after these all, it must be an issue with your AdMob configuration (check everything fine in your AdMob console) or ADs are just not distributed yet (you can check it by looking at the match rate data in AdMob console).
